# Is there a way to run MS-DOS alongside/within Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, games, ms-dos, dosbox

Is there a version of MS-DOS that I can add to Ubuntu? I have old MS-DOS games.

Answer (score 9):

You can try either DOSBox or DOSEMU. Both are available from the repositories - use Ubuntu Software Center or synaptic (if installed) to get them. DOSBox is specifically intended to run games, but I've also used DOSEMU to run DOS games successfully.

Comment: Why do you say to use Synaptic to get them? In 11.10 it's not installed by default, whereas the Ubuntu Software Centre is, and is the recommended way of installing apps.

Comment: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/dosbox/

Comment: @Chris I normally use Synaptic, but obviously any of the software updaters (apt-get, Software Centre, adept in KDE) can be used.

Answer (score 3):

You can run [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/), a free software implementation of DOS inside a virtual machine such as VirtualBox or KVM/QEMU.

Comment: FreeDOS seems now abandoned…

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend taking a look at ScummVM if you have any point 'n' click adventure games.

From the [ScummVM site](http://www.scummvm.org/):

> ScummVM supports many adventure games, including LucasArts SCUMM games
>   (such as Monkey Island 1-3, Day of the Tentacle, Sam & Max, ...), many
>   of Sierra's AGI and SCI games (such as King's Quest 1-6, Space Quest
>   1-5, ...), Discworld 1 and 2, Simon the Sorcerer 1 and 2, Beneath A
>   Steel Sky, Lure of the Temptress, Broken Sword 1 and 2, Flight of the
>   Amazon Queen, Gobliiins 1-3, The Legend of Kyrandia 1-3, many of
>   Humongous Entertainment's children's SCUMM games (including Freddi
>   Fish and Putt Putt games) and many more.

Comment: Firstly, check out if the game isn't supported by ScummVM. If not, use DOSBox - because ScummVM in geneal provides better emulation.

Answer (score 1):

[emu2](https://github.com/dmsc/emu2) is a simple text-mode DOS emulator that is lighter weight than DOSBox.

I do not know what versions of DOS are supported, including if anything specific to MS-DOS is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I use VirtualBox to run old DOS apps.  Personally, I would download the necessary .deb file directly from the VirtualBox site:  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

I understand there is also a slightly older version in the Ubuntu store.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, actually. I'd recommend using DOSBox for DOS-stuff.