# How to get TameDOS running on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, ms-dos, dosbox

Tame Dos is a great program which looks like a "shell" for DOS programs running on Windows.
So, on Windows it works such that applications written for DOS start through TameDOS, of course.

Q: How to make that it runs on Ubuntu in the same way?

I tell you once again, this is a great program!

Comment: I've never heard of that program, nor I understand what you really want, or ask, except that you apparently like this program very much

Comment: This question is getting downvoted much more heavily than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Click the link to install: [`dosbox`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dosbox)[image: Install]. This may be a useful alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I suppose is a link to the program's website: http://www.tamedos.com/.

It looks like this is old, proprietary software, and as such will probably never be ported to Ubuntu unless the original developers decide to make it open-source. You may be better off looking for a modern, open-source [alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74559/is-there-a-way-to-run-ms-dos-alongside-within-ubuntu).