# How to run a MS-DOS application in Wine?

Tags: 11.10, wine

I have read that Wine supports or might support executing MS-DOS apps and games but my question is how. I can't find a way to execute them. I am trying Monkey Island for example or The 7th Guest. Using Wine 1.4rc2 right now.

The following link is why I ask this: http://wiki.winehq.org/WineReleaseCriteria?action=show&redirect=WineReleasePlan

It appears as if DosBox is integrated in Wine but this is the confusion. If it is already integrated, how to execute MS-DOS.

Comment: WINE is for executing Windows applications. Have you tried DOSBox for running DOS games? (Monkey Island seems to be supported by DOSBox)

Comment: @oddfellow: I believe your comment is a perfect answer (Monkey Island indeed works great on DOSBox), would you mind posting it below?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): http://askubuntu.com/q/74559/18612

Comment: Related but not the same. I am asking here for ms-dos inside wine. Outside I know about dosbox, scumm and the rest.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado: The Wine page you linked tells me that the DOSBox integration work is not yet completely done. Quotes: "Features that would be nice to have, but may not make it: DOSBox integration (on our site, now we wait for the next dosbox release)"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DOSBox is a good solution, but Dosemu is a more powerful option; for example, in DOSBox you can't use a printer.

```
$ sudo apt-get install dosemu
```

you can edit the configuration if it doesn't suit you:

```
$ vi /etc/dosemu/dosemu.conf
```

see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/dosemu.bin.1.html

Comment: Dosemu wont work for me
not no problem with dosbox

Comment: +he want to use dos apps with wine ,just double clicking and open without any command line pain

Comment: @AboobackerMk ok, on a script with execute permission, let's call it "dosemu.sh" dosemu /dir_of_program/program.exe that's all the after that just double click on the sh file..

Comment: For the moment I have been told that Dosbox is not yet merged with Wine. When is merged it will work the same way as running Dosbox.

Answer (score 9):

## ScummVM

For classic adventure based on games [SCUMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scumm) I would recommend [ScummVM](http://www.scummvm.org/) ([page in Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/scummvm/)). It is less versatile than DOSBox in that it only runs specific titles, but those titles generally run better in ScummVM than they do in DOSBox. Monkey Island and The 7th Guest are both supported.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way how you can use DOSBox:

1. Install dosbox using Software Center.
2. Install nautilus-open-terminal using Software Center.
3. Open the file browser (Nautilus) and go to the folder that contains your DOS game.
4. Right click on some empty space and select 'Open Terminal Here'.
5. In the terminal type `dosbox .` -- note the single dot at the end of the command.  It is important: it tells DOSBox that you want to make the current directory available as the `C:` drive inside the emulated DOS environment.
6. You'll get a DOSBox window with a `C:\>` prompt.  Type the name of the executable (the file named `something.exe` or `something.com` or `something.bat` that you want to run)
7. Enjoy.

Comment: Installing Nautilus open termainal may crash nautilus in oneric 
many users have this issue including me :)

Comment: Aboobacker Mk, can you link to the bug report in Launchpad?  I've been using nautilus-open-terminal for ages, and haven't noticed any excessive Nautilus crashes yet.

Comment: I didnt send bug reports 
the bug automaticalyy closing nautilus after few second
even the desktop icons disappears
i found solution from a website(i think it was webupd8) it says to uninstall nautilus open terminal plugin 
i did it now no problem

Answer (score -2):

I also would recommend DOSBox. I also know for a fact that "The 7th Guest" will run using it.