# Dos programs in wine

Tags: wine, dosbox

I know that dosbox is not yet integrated with wine, but whenever I double click on a DOS program (with wine) it just opens dosbox and closes it in the next moment. Why does this happen?
Here is the terminal output:

```
tachyonsos@tachyons-desktop:~$ wine '/home/tachyonsos/Desktop/TC.EXE' 
DOSBox version 0.74
Copyright 2002-2010 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
---
CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file /home/tachyonsos/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/tachyonsos/Temp/cfg1453.tmp
MIXER:Got different values from SDL: freq 44100, blocksize 512
ALSA:Can't subscribe to MIDI port (65:0) nor (17:0)
MIDI:Opened device:none
```

BTW is it a bug?

**Linked QUESTION**

1. [How to run a MS-DOS application in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105171/how-to-run-a-ms-dos-application-in-wine)

Comment: Why do you want dosbox integrated in WINE? A linux installer exists. http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1

Comment: I already installed wine and dosbox

Comment: Aha, I didn't read you question properly.

Comment: I installed dosbox via ucs ,not via wine

Comment: maybe if you run `cmd` under Wine with parameter tc.exe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Top post edit**
By the way, I see the issue you're talking about with the double-clicking. Just launch dosbox and run, or make sure your binary is inside of the .wine/drive_c if that's not the behaviour you want.
**end edit**
You say dosbox is throwing an error when you run:
`tachyonsos@tachyons-desktop:~$ wine '/home/tachyonsos/Desktop/TC.EXE'`
Correct your sound settings.
If that doesn't work, put it inside the `~/.wine/drive_c`.

On my box, when I installed via software center it put a compiled binary in /usr/bin like this:
[image]

Configuration files are in ~/.dosbox.  The [wiki](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf#midiconfig_.3D_id_of_MIDI_device) tells us how to configure the file and determine our midi parameters.  To get those utilities we need `sudo apt-get install pmidi`.

Then we can see something like this:
[image]

So with `gedit ~/.dosbox/dosbox-0.74.conf` we can make this:

```
midiconfig=
```

look like this:

```
midiconfig=14:0
```

Which gives us this:
[image]

Next I added all the way at the end on the next line from where it says `MOUNT lines here`

```
mount C: /home/username/dosboxc
```

Now when I double click an exe it tries to load in dosbox, as it should since I installed that last.

Now I make launchers for the EXEs I want to launch with wine to include the wine command and the URL.

You don't launch things in Dosbox with shortcuts.  You load up dosbox and run them.  At least that's what I do, and it works for me.

I definitely see no bug here.

Oh, and finally since I installed it anyway:
[image]
I needed to test that the sound was working anyway.

Comment: dosbox working perfectly in my pc ,but why the integration with wine fails?

Comment: it doesn't.  put anything you want to run under ~/.wine/drive_c/ and it works fine

Comment: output winevdm: Cannot start DOS application C:\TC.EXE
         because the DOS memory range is unavailable.
         Try running this application with DOSBox.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it works fine if you run dosbox directly, but there are issues with Wine integration. I think people aren't getting your question.

Wine is supposed to be able to look at a windows executable and hand it off to DOSBox if it determines it needs 16 bit DOS code.

> output winevdm: Cannot start DOS application C:\TC.EXE because the DOS memory range is unavailable. Try running this application with DOSBox. – Tachyons Apr 25 '12 at 17:44
>   Make sure DOSBox is installed and "echo $PATH" contains the directory for the DOSBox binary.

I myself get 
    wine C:/DOS_Games/convert.exe
    DOSBox version 0.74
    Copyright 2002-2010 DOSBox Team, published under GNU GPL.
    ---
    CONFIG:Loading primary settings from config file /Users/jeremiah/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/jeremiah/Temp/cfg208.tmp
    MIDI:Opened device:coreaudio

This shows Wine is using an incorrect configuration file. Unfortunately Wine generates this file each time it calls DOSBox so fixing this will require submitting a patch or report to Wine's Bugzilla.

Maybe there are additional configuration settings that would correct the generated configuration?

Comment: If you open winevdm.c and set "args[1]" & "args[2]" inside the "start_dosbox" function to "NULL" and then recompile, then Wine will correctly open DOSBox. Updating to the SVN version of DOSBox may also help (http://dosbox.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dosbox/dosbox/trunk/?view=tar) but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score -4):

No, it's not a bug, you can't run the DOS programs in Ubuntu using Wine because it only supports Windows or DOS.

Comment: you can't run dos because it supports dos makes NO sense