# How do I change screen resolution in Dosbox through Wine?

Tags: wine, resolution, screen, games, dosbox

My old DOS game (Tomb Raider I) installs and then runs fine with Wine by [making use of Dosbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124726/dos-programs-in-wine). Everything works (keys, audio, [full screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175763/how-do-i-make-dosbox-show-in-full-screen-mode)) but I am unable to adjust the resulting screen resolution.

The display setting is always at the lowest possible resulting in heavily pixelated output. Changing the game settings has no effect. I already tried a better resolution from Wine windows configuration, and from changing settings in my `~/.dosbox/dosbox.conf` but these seem not to be respected.

My system: Ubuntu 12.10 amd64, Wine 1.4, Dosbox 0.74, Nvida Gforce 6, nvidia-current-updates 304.51.

How do I make Wine to call Dosbox with my custom settings for screen resolution and geometry?

Comment: Have you played with the machine parameter in the config file? http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2008/03/16/dosbox-graphic-and-machine-emulation-cga-vga-tandy-pcjr-hercules/

Comment: `Dosbox` can run natively on Ubuntu without using `wine`, then perhaps all the options in the conf would be available. The original Tomb Raider can look quite good if you remember to use the 3dfx DOS version. I would just use `wine` to install it and then replace the original executable with the 3dfx executable. Then you can move the folder and run the game with the native Ubuntu version of Dosbox once your conf has been set up. You can run it with `dosbox -conf /my/game/conf.conf`. You can even use a joypad if you use `QJoypad` and set up the keys.

Comment: Yeah, I can adjust screen settings for Dosbox from the .conf but I am still wondering how to make Wine respect these.

Comment: I don't think `wine` will respect the settings properly until `dosbox` is integrated into `wine`, but I'll see if there are any possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this tread is a little old, but I just ran into this problem myself and solved it.

In the install folder that `wine` uses to run the game, there is a `DOSBOX.CONF` file (mine read `dosboxDK.conf`, where `DK` was the initials of the game). If you edit this as you would the normal `dosbox.conf` you will get the results you want.

Comment: Thank you for the notice... I'll test this later. Answering old questions is definitely **encouraged** :)