# Yardi on Ubuntu, Patric, digitalbeachbum

Tags: wine, dhcp, playonlinux

I am trying to run an old DOS real estate management program Yardi 4.0 on ubuntu.  Has anybody done it successfully?

I had read a post here from a user 'digitalbeachbum', Patric,  earlier last year who had done it but I could no longer find the message or the user.

Patric, if you see this message, can you give me some insight please?

Thank you!

Lu

/ Yardi WINE PlayOnLinux .EXE Ubuntu 12.04 not communicating with DHCP /

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a MS-DOS application in Wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/105171/how-to-run-a-ms-dos-application-in-wine)

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a UBUNTU-Site and not a Microsoft-Site. So why would you ask to have it installed on Windows-System.

The person you were looking for has installed it on Ubuntu in combo with wine, thats a little bit different.

I still have a recommendation though, try it with DOSBOX.

http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1

Comment: Right, cut/paste error.  I posted it somewhere else for Windows first.  My post is corrected. Thanks for the feedback.