# DOS Executable files

Tags: ms-dos

Is there any way to run a program that uses a dos executable file on a desktop? I have one program that is a must for my work and I cannot find anything comparable in Ubuntu aps.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/74559/is-there-a-way-to-run-ms-dos-alongside-within-ubuntu/74567#74567?

Answer (score 0):

There is - through dosemu. You can get it through software center or apt. Place the executable into .dosemu/drive_c directory in you home , and fire up dosemu. You can find the executable with dir command,  and run with ./